# Azure Policy Assignment - Exclude Resource Type(s)

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I have an Azure Policy that validates the Region of 2 resource groups via 2 Assignments. The allowed Regions are South Central US and global. My problem is that there are policy violation in each resource group that I can't seem to get rid of. For example, in one resource group, the resource which violates the policy is the Assignment itself, which I cannot change the Region for (or I don't know how to) and I can't see it as an excludable resource in the Exclusions list. For the 2nd resource group, the failing items are a number of SQL database managed instance vulnerability assessments and a number of Security Assessments; the interesting part about these, when I try to view the resources Azure can't find them, just returns "Resource Not Found", so unsurprisingly I can't exclude these either. So right now I seem to be stuck with a Policy and 2 Assignments that cannot achieve 100% compliance, and I'm hoping someone can offer tips to resolve. Perhaps a way to exclude a Type of resource instead of by name, but I'm open to any ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer while digging through the pre-canned Policies. You can put a restriction on the type field in the policyRule.if section as per below. Just have to specify the types that should be excluded.

```
"policyRule": {
  "if": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "field": "location",
        "notIn": "[parameters('listOfAllowedLocations')]"
      },
      {
        "field": "location",
        "notEquals": "global"
      },
      {
        "field": "type",
        "notEquals": "Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory/b2cDirectories"
      }
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding type restriction to your policy will help, but you'll need to maintain the list of excluded resource types.

If you change the [mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#mode) of your policy to `Indexed`, then your policy will only evaluate resources which actually have a `location` field.