# Azure Policy - Find Ressources without Tags

Tags: azure, tags, azure-policy

Is it possible to define a Policy to find Resources without Tags?

I would like to define this Policy to list all of Items at the "Compliance" Point at the Policy Tab.

I have looked at the Definitions but I can not find this scenario.

Did someone build a Policy about this scenario?
Or can someone help me to build this Policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this definition:

```
{
    "mode": "Indexed",
    "policyRule": {
        "if": {
            "value": "[less(length(field('tags')), 1)]",
            "equals": "true"
        },
        "then": {
            "effect": "audit"
        }
    }
}
```

Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#value-examples

Comment: Thanks for your Answer.

I have forgot to post my Answer here. This Articel was the Answer for my Question and i have to configure it with this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [***MS DOC***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-policies):-

> While creating a policy, you may prevent resources from being deployed
> to your subscription that don't match your organization's tags.
> Instead of manually adding tags or searching for non-compliant
> resources, ***you construct a policy that applies the required tags
> automatically during deployment***.

For more information please refer this [***SO THREAD|Azure Policy Assignment - Exclude Resource Type(s)***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61143237/azure-policy-assignment-exclude-resource-types?rq=1)